# is it possible to find only the system call names made by any c program and store that names one by one in a vector?

Tags: c

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{
    char buf;
    int sourcefile,destfile,n;//copy a text from one file to another file
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,"prgm1 <sourcefile> <destination file>\n",50);   
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
         sourcefile=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
         if(sourcefile==-1)
         {
            perror("SOURCE FILE ERROR");
            exit(0);
         }
         else
         {
            destfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY | O_CREAT , 0641);
            if(destfile==-1)
            {
                perror("DESTINATION FILE ERROR");
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                while((n=read(sourcefile,&buf,1)) != 0)
                {
                    write( destfile, &buf, 1 );
                }
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, "FILES COPIED\n" , 15);    
                close(sourcefile);
                close(destfile);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this above program what are the system calls made and their names should be stored in vector created by c program.
I can trace the system calls using strace but i want to know only the names and their sequence of system calls need to be stored.

Comment: I think `strace(1)` or `ptrace(2)` could help.

Comment: what is a vector in this context?